# R writing style - require vs. ::

Tags: r, namespaces, package

OK, we're all familiar with double colon operator in R. Whenever I'm about to write some function, I use `require(<pkgname>)`, but I was always thinking about using `::` instead. Using `require` in custom functions is better practice than `library`, since `require` returns warning and `FALSE`, unlike `library`, which returns error if you provide a name of non-existent package.

On the other hand, `::` operator gets the variable from the package, while `require` loads whole package (at least I hope so), so speed differences came first to my mind. `::` must be faster than `require`.

And I did some analysis in order to check that - I've written two simple functions that load `read.systat` function from `foreign` package, with `require` and `::` respectively, hence import `Iris.syd` dataset that ships with `foreign` package, replicated functions 1000 times each (which was shamelessly arbitrary), and... crunched some numbers.

Strangely (or not) I found significant differences in terms of user CPU and elapsed time, while there were no significant differences in terms of system CPU. And yet more strange conclusion: `::` is actually slower! Documentation for `::` is very blunt, and just by looking at sources it's obvious that `::` should perform better!

**require**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/r

## with require
fn1 <- function() {
  require(foreign)
  read.systat("Iris.syd", to.data.frame=TRUE)
}

## times
n <- 1e3

sink("require.txt")
print(t(replicate(n, system.time(fn1()))))
sink()
```

**double colon**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/r

## with ::
fn2 <- function() {
  foreign::read.systat("Iris.syd", to.data.frame=TRUE)
}

## times
n <- 1e3


sink("double_colon.txt")
print(t(replicate(n, system.time(fn2()))))
sink()
```

Grab CSV data [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8566396/sim/require%20vs%20colon/require_colon_sim.csv). Some stats:

```
user CPU:     W = 475366    p-value = 0.04738  MRr =  975.866    MRc = 1025.134
system CPU:   W = 503312.5  p-value = 0.7305   MRr = 1003.8125   MRc =  997.1875
elapsed time: W = 403299.5  p-value < 2.2e-16  MRr =  903.7995   MRc = 1097.2005
```

MRr is mean rank for `require`, MRc ibid for `::`. I must have done something wrong here. It just doesn't make any sense... Execution time for `::` seems way faster!!! I may have screwed something up, you shouldn't discard that option...

OK... I've wasted my time in order to see that there is some difference, and I carried out completely useless analysis, so, back to the question:

"*Why should one prefer `require` over `::` when writing a function?*"

=)

Comment: Is this for standalone functions or functions in a package?

Comment: Also, you would normally require() once at the top of your script, not once in every function call.

Comment: It's for standalone functions. I'm developing a web-application, and since RApache starts new R session upon each HTTP request, I'm trying to avoid unnecessary server load. This example is inappropriate - once you import a file, the job's done, but in an interactive webapp with bunch of AJAX calls, this may be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "Why should one prefer require over ::
>   when writing a function?"

I usually prefer `require` due to the nice TRUE/FALSE return value that lets me deal with the possibility of the package not being available up front before getting into the code.  Crash as early as possible instead of halfway through your analysis.

I only use `::` when I need to make sure I am using the correct version of a function, not a version from some other package that is masking the name.

> On the other hand, :: operator gets
>   the variable from the package, while
>   require loads whole package (at least
>   I hope so), so speed differences came
>   first to my mind. :: must be faster
>   than require.

I think you may be ignoring the effects of *lazy loading* which is used by the `foreign` package according to [the first page of its manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/foreign.pdf).  Essentially, packages that use lazy loading defer the loading of objects, such as functions, until the objects are called upon for the first time.  So your argument that "`::` must be faster than require" is not necessarily true as `foreign` is not loading all of its contents into memory when you attach it with `require`.  For full details on lazy loading, see [Prof. Ripley's article](http://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-2.pdf) in RNews, Volume 4, Issue 2.

Comment: You are so right... and this may be package-dependent problem. Oh, and thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 7):

Since the time to load a package is almost always small compared to the time you spend trying to figure out what the code you wrote six months ago was about, in this case coding for clarity is the most important thing.

For scripts, having a call to `require` or `library` at the start lets you know which packages you need straight away.

Similarly, calling `require` (or a wrapper like `requirePackage` in `Hmisc` or `try_require` in `ggplot2`) at the start of a function is the most unambiguous way of showing that you need to use that package.

`::` should be reserved for cases when you have naming conflicts between packages – compare, e.g.,

```
Hmisc::is.discrete
```

and

```
plyr::is.discrete
```