# What are the double colons (::) in R?

Tags: r, scope, namespaces, operators, scoping

I am following a tutorial in Rbloggers and found the use of double colons, I looked online, but I couldn't find an explanation for their use. 
Here is an example of their use.

```
df <- dplyr::data_frame(
  year = c(2015, NA, NA, NA), 
  trt = c("A", NA, "B", NA)
)
```

I understand it creates a data frame but I don't understand their purpose.

Comment: see the help files... `?'::'`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to access the characters help in R!

Comment: `help("::")` can also be used if `?` gives you troubles.  Functions can always be written in quotes.

Comment: Strongly related: [Is it good practice to call functions in a package via ::](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23232791/903061)

Answer (score 50):

As you probably have looked up the help page by now  usage of `::` helps to access the exact function from that specific package. When you load `dplyr` you probably got a message as follows..

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
       intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

So, for instance, if you would like to use `intersect` function from dplyr or base package, you need to specify using the `::` double colons. Usage will be as follows

```
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
first <- mtcars[1:20, ]
second <- mtcars[10:20, ]
dplyr::intersect(first, second)
base::intersect(first, second)
```

***Update: Added additional explanation***

Note: The sequence you load libraries determine the preferential access of the specific functions. Developers of different package tend to use same function names. However, when R encounters a function, it runs through the different libraries that particular session has loaded in a sequential manner. You can check the packages in a session by running `(.packages())`

```
 [1] "tidyr"      "data.table" "dplyr"      "stats"     
 [5] "graphics"   "grDevices"  "utils"      "datasets"  
 [9] "methods"    "base"
```

As you can see in my example session above, `tidyr` is the last library I loaded, which is r session 1st entry. So, when you use any function in your code , first it is searched in `tidyr` -> then `data.table` -> then `dplyr` and so on, finally the `base` package is looked up. So, in this process when there is function name overlaps between packages the one which loaded the last masks the previous ones. To avoid this masking, you specify in R code where to look for the function. Hence, here `base::intersect`, will use the function from base library instead of the `dplyr`. Alternatively, you can use to avoid loading of complete library. There are positives and negatives with this. Read the links and learn more.

run and check the differences. 
 Here are some resources for you to get an understanding.

[Compare library(), require(), ::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372145/r-writing-style-require-vs)

[Namespace](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)

Comment: It s better to use `search()` than `.packages()` since names can resolved to attached list/environments/etc as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't make clear a very important point: you must have installed a package for its functions to be available for extraction using ```::```. (But you need not have _loaded_ that package)

Answer (score 20):

There may be multiple functions with the same name in multiple packages.  The double colon operator allows you to specify the specific function you want:

```
package::functionname
```