# R: What do you call the :: and ::: operators and how do they differ?

Tags: r, operators, terminology

I'm wondering how the functions of the `::` and `:::` operators differ in R.

However, I can't figure out what these operators are called and so a google or SO search has not proven helpful. I also get an error when I try `?::` in R.

So...

1. What are the `::` and `:::` operators called?
2. **How do `::` and `:::` differ? (i.e., what *exactly* does each do)?**

Comment: what-are-the-double-colons-in-r http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240971/what-are-the-double-colons-in-r/35241015

Comment: @hrbrmstr Though I certainly agree that the two questions should be linked, I disagree that my question should be closed as a duplicate. My question is *really* asking a separate question not asked nor answered in the question you've linked. My question asks how the two colon operators differ.

Comment: _"see the help files... ?'::' "_  (the first comment) is all you needed from that link. it's def a dup. petition to have it reopened. i'm sure you'll find some sympathetic moderators.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out there is a unique way to access help info for operators such as these colons: *add quotations marks around the operator.* [E.g., `?'::'` or `help(":::")`].

- Also, instead of quotation marks, back-ticks (i.e, ` ) also work.

---

### Double Colon Operator and Triple Colon Operator

The answer to the question can be found on the help page for **"Double Colon and Triple Colon Operators"** (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html)).

> For a package pkg, pkg::name returns the value of the **exported** variable name in namespace pkg, whereas pkg:::name returns the value of the **internal** variable name. The package namespace will be loaded if it was not loaded before the call, but the package will not be attached to the search path.

The difference can be seen by examining the code of each:

```
> `::`
function (pkg, name) 
{
    pkg <- as.character(substitute(pkg))
    name <- as.character(substitute(name))
    getExportedValue(pkg, name)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000000136e2ae8>
<environment: namespace:base>

> `:::`
function (pkg, name) 
{
    pkg <- as.character(substitute(pkg))
    name <- as.character(substitute(name))
    get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000013482f50>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

**::** calls `getExportedValue(pkg, name)`, **returning the value of the *exported* variable `name`** in the package's namespace.

**:::** calls `get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE)`, searching for the object `name` in the Namespace environment of the package, and **returning the value of the *internal* variable `name`**.

---

So, what exactly is a *namespace*?

This [site](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) does a good job of explaining the concept of namespaces in R. Importantly:

> As the name suggests, namespaces provide “spaces” for “names”. They provide a context for looking up the value of an object associated with a name.

Comment: It means you can do ridiculous things like `\`::\`("stats","sd")(1:5)` which is equivalent to `sd(1:5)`

Comment: `\`%>%\`('magrittr', 'sd')(1:5)` 錯誤發生在 "magrittr" %>% "sd"：不适用于非函数, how to apply on `%>%`?

Comment: print(`::`) now returns `function (pkg, name)  .Primitive("::")` (R 4.1.1).