# R - Could not find a specific function showing in Source Code of a R package

Tags: r

I am studying a R package named "catch", and trying to code that in python. I use "View" function to get the source code from this R package, and find its function "catch" calls another function "tsda". However, I could not find any information about this function "tsda". I tried 
1. View(tsda)
2. ?tsda
3. ??tsda
4. tsda
None of them gave me any information. Can anyone tell me how to find this function?

Comment: [`tsda`](https://github.com/cran/catch/blob/3dd5d41cc00575ba31fad9ac19c6a1ba8012d3ba/R/tensor_main.R) is a function within the package that is not exported. If you're curious about reading the function, that link I just gave should suffice. If you need to look at it *in R or RStudio*, then you should be able to find it with `catch:::tsda`.

Comment: Related, though perhaps not perfect dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35240971/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41582136/3358272