# Populate a dataframe in r with different values

Tags: r

Could anyone answer this?
I have a dataframe (thousands of rows) with a particular column name `Name` and I want to modify the dataframe based on the column `Name` e.g. I have a sample dataframe

```
df1<-data.frame(Id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
       Name=c('Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_C','Plant_C','Plant_C'), 
       Value=c(100,100,100,100,55,55,55,90,90,90),
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now, according to the column`Name` the new columns namely `Availability` and `Status` should be added/populate with the values shown in the dataframe `df2`. The first value of the row with `Yes` and `0` and rest of the values for the same `Name` should be `No` and empty `` and so on.

```
df2<-data.frame(Id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
                Name=c('Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_C','Plant_C','Plant_C'), 
                Value=c(100,100,100,100,55,55,55,90,90,90),
                Availability=c('Yes','No','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No'),
                Status =c(0,'','','',0,'','',0,'',''),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I can add only one type of the value like,

```
df1$Availability<-'Yes'
df1$Status<-0
```

But don't understand how to populate `df1` in order to get `df2`. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe `merge(df1,df2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr` pipe can do it by grouping and mutating de data set.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Availability = c("Yes", rep("No", n() - 1)), 
         Status = c(0, rep("", n() - 1)))
## A tibble: 10 x 5
## Groups:   Name [3]
#      Id Name    Value Availability Status
#   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>        <chr> 
# 1     1 Plant_A   100 Yes          "0"   
# 2     2 Plant_A   100 No           ""    
# 3     3 Plant_A   100 No           ""    
# 4     4 Plant_A   100 No           ""    
# 5     5 Plant_B    55 Yes          "0"   
# 6     6 Plant_B    55 No           ""    
# 7     7 Plant_B    55 No           ""    
# 8     8 Plant_C    90 Yes          "0"   
# 9     9 Plant_C    90 No           ""    
#10    10 Plant_C    90 No           ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match against unique values from `Name`. Match will retrieve first apparition of every element in his first argument.

```
df1$Availability = 'No'
df1$Status = ''


df1$Availability[match(unique(df1$Name), df1$Name)] <- 'Yes'
df1$Status[match(unique(df1$Name), df1$Name)] <- 0
```

Comment: did you try with triple colon ::: operator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582136/r-what-do-you-call-the-and-operators-and-how-do-they-differ

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution for posterity:

```
library(data.table)

df1<-data.table(
  Id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
  Name=c('Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_A','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_B','Plant_C','Plant_C','Plant_C'), 
  Value=c(100,100,100,100,55,55,55,90,90,90))

df1[, `:=` (Availability = c("Yes", rep("", .N-1)),
            Status = c(0, rep("", .N-1))),
    by="Name"]

df1[]
#>     Id    Name Value Availability Status
#>  1:  1 Plant_A   100          Yes      0
#>  2:  2 Plant_A   100                    
#>  3:  3 Plant_A   100                    
#>  4:  4 Plant_A   100                    
#>  5:  5 Plant_B    55          Yes      0
#>  6:  6 Plant_B    55                    
#>  7:  7 Plant_B    55                    
#>  8:  8 Plant_C    90          Yes      0
#>  9:  9 Plant_C    90                    
#> 10: 10 Plant_C    90
```