# How does R access the package namespace without a call to library?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was helping somebody with their code recently and they asked me why it was possible to use functions from a certain package (e.g. `dplyr`) without explicitly 'loading' (and attaching them) to the search path within R.

Specifically, why it is possible to write:

```
dplyr::mutate(...)
```

As opposed to:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(...)
```

When you use `::`, it doesn't appear to automatically 'attach' the functions from the namespace `dplyr` onto the search path. That only happens when you call `library()`. This confuses me slightly: when you use the `::` approach, how does R find the function `mutate()` within `dplyr` without it being attached to the search path?

Comment: you can read the documentation with ? '`'::'`'

Comment: So it says that the package namespace 'will be loaded if it was not loaded before the call (to `::`), but the package will not be attached to the search path'. Makes sense, but I thought that 'loading' a package and 'attaching to the search path' were synonymous: how does R locate the actual function inside a package without attaching it to the search path?

Comment: The `::` call effectively explicitly tells R *not* to look in the search path, but to search in the package namespace instead. You can test this by trying to find a function that's not in `dplyr` and you can see it then ignores the search path altogether (e.g. `dplyr::mean` gives `Error: 'mean' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`)

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider making use of [`with`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/with). `with` is traditionally is used to undertake operations on the data but combined with [`asNamespace`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ns-internals) can be used to access functions from the packages without the need to load the package.

```
with(asNamespace("dplyr"),
     select(mtcars, cyl) %>%
         mutate(cyl_two = cyl * 2)
)
```

You can use `::` and `:::` to access a single function from a package, accounting for exported or not exported functions. If you look at the code of [double and triple colon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41582180/1655567) operators you will see that those leverage very similar mechanism. Package name is used to construct an environment via `asNamespace` and `get`<sup>1</sup> function is used to source the function.

Broadly speaking, a potentially efficient way of thinking about that is comparing package functions to objects in an environment. By calling `::`, `:::` or `with` we can reference those objects.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case of `::` the actual function is `getExportedValue`.