# what does double dots means in R when trying loading a library

Tags: r

> how to unpack a library in R using ::

```
ggplot::data$price'
```

> instead of writing code like library(ggplot)

Comment: accessing a member of `ggplot` (in the scope)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the double colons (::) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240971/what-are-the-double-colons-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load a library, then you can make each function of a package explicit.

```
data(mtcars)

ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars) + 
    ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))
```